# SQL query to exclude rows from the main query based on a sub-query that checks ALL rows exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause

I have a query that returns data from a main table (Works) and pulls in some addition data (Publishers) using a sub-query in the SELECT list, that is then grouped up into a CSV list. Something like this:

| WID | Work Name | Publishers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Work Title 1 | Red Publisher 1, Blue Publisher 1 |
| 2 | Work Title 2 | Red Publisher 1, Red Publisher 2 |
| 3 | Work Title 3 | Yellow Publisher 1, Red Publisher 3 |
| 4 | Work Title 4 | Green Publisher 1 |
| 5 | Work Title 5 | Red Publisher 2 |

I need to modify the WHERE clause to exclude rows where **ALL** the linked Publishers per Work appear in another table.

For example, if I wanted to exclude all the 'Red Publisher' data where they are the sole Publisher(s):

| ExcludedPublishers |
| --- |
| Red Publisher 1 |
| Red Publisher 2 |
| Red Publisher 3 |

I found a solution using counts, but the performance is unacceptable, going from a few seconds to 30-40 seconds. The main table has about 3 million rows in total, but the query is filtered on other data. Therefore, the returned record set is much less <= 1000 rows.

This is the query comparing the count of linked records against the count of those linked record which exist in the exclusion table, which should not be equal:

```
SELECT w.*
     , stuff( ( SELECT ',' + p.name FROM Publishers p WHERE  p.wid = w.wid FOR XML PATH ('') ), 1, 1, '') publishers
FROM   Works w
WHERE  w.wid <= 4 -- Limit to the Works returned for this demo
 AND   ( SELECT count(*) FROM Publishers p2 WHERE p2.wid = w.wid ) -- Number of linked Publishers
    != ( SELECT count(*) -- Number of linked Publishers that exist in the ExcludedPublishers table
         FROM   ExcludedPublishers xp 
         WHERE  xp.pub_code IN ( SELECT p3.code FROM Publishers p3 WHERE p3.wid = w.wid ) 
       );
```

Returning:

| WID | Work Name | Publishers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Work Title 1 | Red Publisher 1, Blue Publisher 1 |
| 3 | Work Title 3 | Yellow Publisher 1, Red Publisher 3 |
| 4 | Work Title 4 | Green Publisher 1 |

Here is SQL Fiddle detailing this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60e2cf/6 and I'm using *SQL Server 2014*.

My question is, is there a more performant way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Performance questions require an execution plan. Please provide one using "Paste The Plan".

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyviQqEAh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the query below

```
 SELECT w.*
    , STUFF( ( SELECT ', ' + p.name FROM Publishers p WHERE  p.wid = w.wid FOR XML PATH ('') ), 1, 1, '')  AS publishers
 FROM Works w
 JOIN Publishers p ON p.wid = w.wid
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ExcludedPublishers
    WHERE pub_code = p.code
 )
```

Comment: Some explanation about why this might help would be useful.

Comment: This worked out to be the best solution, thanks. Although, I used a LEFT OUTER JOIN on Publishers because there may be Works without Publishers.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to test performance, but perhaps something like this:

```sql
SELECT w.*, stuff(x.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM   Works w
CROSS APPLY  ( 
  select ',' + name
  from (
    SELECT p.name as name, count(*) over() cnt1, count(ep.pub_code) over()AS cnt2
    FROM Publishers p
    left join ExcludedPublishers ep
      ON ep.pub_code = p.code
    WHERE  p.wid = w.wid
   ) x
  where not cnt2 = cnt1
  FOR XML PATH (''), type
) q(x)
WHERE  w.wid <= 5 -- Limit to the Works with linked Publishers for this demo
and x is not null
```

It should materialize all publishers per work once and then do one simple filter as well as STUFF which shouldn't be too expensive.

The idea is to create two window counts, one per publisher and one per excluded publishers, this allows to keep our original data and getting counts which cannot be done by aggregation. If the two counts match, exclude these from processing.
Also, to be able to both filter and select the value, i move it to CROSS APPLY which allows reusing the calculation easily.

Btw, a bit of a digression,but you might want to start looking to upgrade your SQL Server, 2014 is old and doesn't support nicer stuff like STRING_AGG, JSON etc which makes a lot of problems simple

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this performed worse than the original query on real data.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryNESvu16